# Remove "?xx=yy" part of the querystring parameter from $args in nginx

Tags: nginx

*Developer here, with close to zero *nix abilities. After googling for a few hours I ended up here hoping to find a solution to this problem:*

I have a simple site set up like this:

```
server {
 listen 80 default_server;
 listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

 root /data/www/example.com;

 server_name example.com;

 location / {
    index index.html$args;
    try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri/ /index.html$args =404;
 }
}
```

and I need nginx to forward routes like

```
example.com/path1/path2/path3?param=value
```

to

```
example.com/index.html/path1/path2/path3
```

(I have an angularJS app which listens for this kind of routes)

The problem is that whenever I get a route which includes a *?param=value* at the end I get the 404 page. All the other nested routes are forwarded correctly (ie: `example.com/path1/path2/path3` goes to `example.com/index.html/path1/path2/path3`).

Any ideas to get me out of trouble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `$args` inserted in inappropriate places. As indicated by [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_args), the `$args` (which is equivalent to `$query_string`) contains everything following the `?` separator. The `$uri` contains everything including the pathinfo.

`try_files` is checking for the existence of filenames by concatenating the `root` with the provided element. So you should probably be using:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?path=$uri;
```

The final element should be a default URI (such as `/index.html`) or an error action (such as `=404`) and not *both*. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

I am not familiar with sending pathinfo to an HTML file, other than by using a parameter. `index.php$uri` works ok, but `index.html$uri` just yields a 500 error.

Comment: The part that helped my version of the route was the one with the final element which should be either `/index.html` or the error code. Afterwards I tried your version and it worked as well. Thanks a lot, @Richard Smith